# Difference between Content Based Recommender and K means clustering

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, recommendation-engine

As the name says, it's a relatively straightforward question. In both, we calculate the similarity between two items (could be using different measures, of course). And we recommend the items closest to the item user just used. Can anybody explain to me how the two are different things?

Comment: In web search we also compute similarity. So this is also the same? And since it involves sorting, everything is just QuickSort anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a conceptual perspective, a [`Content Based Recommender`](http://facweb.cs.depaul.edu/mobasher/classes/ect584/Papers/ContentBasedRS.pdf) is a recommender system and it does not necessary work with clustering strategies, instead of this, it could implement any strategy. A Content Based Recommender could apply classifications, prediction, clustering or merge all these strategies to provide a recommendation for something we call as a `Decision Support System`.

[`K-means`](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2346830?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) is a strategy that use the atrtibutes of a dataset as vectors and based on euclidean distance between the items, it meansures a given `k` number of clusters of each item on the dataset belongs.

A `Content Based Recommender` could use `k-means` as part of a strategy to provider a recommendation to a `Decision Support System`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that does make it clearer to me.

Comment: Is there a way we can evaluate such models cuz we don't have target labels so how can we say if it's good or bad.